# How do I check for the subclass type at runtime in the Spring Controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa, server

I have an API that takes a Baseclass as a RequestBody. I have say 3 entities (A, B and C that extend my BaseClass)and 3 corresponding JPA repositories for those. In the @controller or @service class how do I know which subclass is the RequestBody referring to? I have used @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes annotations to serialize and deserialize and so that is not a problem.

1. I want figure out the type of @RequestBody object e.g if @requestBody object is instanceof A or B or C?
2. Is it good to use instanceof in this case?
3. If I use instanceof and if I later want to add 50 more entities and say 10 more JPA repositories then I cannot possibly keep adding if/else for those instanceof conditions. In that case what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes you can use instance of in this case. However, if you 10 more classes you won't be happy to add 10 more if/then/else blocks. In this case, two approaches come to my mind:

1. Visitor Pattern: This is exactly the pattern you want when you have this kind of chained  instanceof  ifs (e.g. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor/java/example).
2. If this is the only place where you have this the chained ifs the visitor might be overkill. You could create a Map Class -> Lambda Function. Initialize it in you constructor and the look up the desired behaviour for each class.
3. You create a Map VO -> Entity. Then you can query the Application Context for the Repository for the entity.